# Laravel PHP Global object

Tags: php, laravel, singleton

I'm new to the world of OOP and I'm trying to make a Laravel application.

The app I'm making is to facilitate a game. The game has got a startdate and an enddate. However throughout my application it's nice to know the period of the game (enddate - startdate) and the relative period compared to a year ( period / 365 ). I defined the start date and end date in a configuration file.

Is it wise to create a class where I set the period and the relative period? The class should only be instantiated once ... so a singleton?

Any pointers/best practices are welcome!

Comment: Is your game intended to only persist for one session in the browser?

Comment: I would put it in the session.

Comment: @McRed no, during a period of about 3 weeks users have to try to do some energy savings. So the setting is the same for every registered user.

Comment: Is the game available for every user between the same dates or is it 3 weeks from when a user registers to play?

Comment: @RossWilson: it is the same for every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a static class so it never has to be instantiated.

If you want to create a singleton you can check the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding-basics):

```
$this->app->singleton('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
    return new HelpSpot\API($app->make('HttpClient'));
});
```

Once you've added this to the `register` method of a service provider (e.g. `AppServiceProvider`) you can access it by type hinting it inside a controller method or by calling `$api = resolve('HelpSpot\API');` (see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#resolving))

Comment: Great, made a class which has a method to return the properties. In the AppServiceProvider I registered the singleton. Works great :)

Comment: But can I update its properties? And can I then get this object with new properties?